# Provide images from an internal CMS

Tags: nginx

How can I achieve that the nginx is providing images from a backend. 
If a user calls http://example.com/images/1.jpg, the image should be provided from the internal CMS. I tried try_files, proxy_pass and something like that. But presumably I'm off the track, and this is the complete wrong approach...

```
location = /images {
    rewrite /images/(.*) /images/$1 last; 
    proxy_pass http://192.168.0.5:12345/CMS;
}
```

thx.

Comment: remove `rewrite /images/(.*) /images/$1 last;` And what url should `http://example.com/images/1.jpg` should translate to?

Comment: The url should not be changed/translated...The user should get the image from the "CMS". So the result should be the image itself.

Comment: When I say translated, I mean when user is requesting `/images/1.png`. Where does CMS host it? On `http://192.168.0.5:12345/CMS/images/1.png` or on `http://192.168.0.5:12345/CMS/1.png` or some place else?

Comment: On the first one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use below

```
location /images {
    proxy_pass http://192.168.0.5:12345/CMS;
}
```

`=` is used for absolute url. Now see it should work.